# Emacs query-replace with newlines

Tags: emacs

I have the a string like this (separtred by asterisk) :

```
abc*dddd*fffff*
```

i need to replace the `*` with a newline. i.e the result should be:

```
abc
dddd
fffff
```

How can I do this in Emacs?  I tried `query-replace` but pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 49):

Do quote the enter key: `C-q C-j`. There, `C-q` inserts the next key literally and `C-j` gives newline.

Comment: `C-j` produces ASCII 0x0a (\n, newline, linefeed). The ENTER key produces 0x0d (\r, carriage-return). Anyone who knows the background for this?

Comment: Historically, control keys were represented (over serial terminals and other byte-stream protocols) as `^A` = 1, `^B` = 2, and so on. And so `^J` is 10. ENTER was (arbitrarily? I don't know) the same as `^M`, or  13.

Comment: Old post, but the key you are calling ENTER is actually called the carriage return key, while the ENTER key is the one on the numeric key pad.

Answer (score 12):

Try `query-replace`   <kbd>enter</kbd>   *   <kbd>enter</kbd>   <kbd>M-j</kbd>   <kbd>enter</kbd>    !   <kbd>enter</kbd>